# Django best practice. Forms

Tags: python, django

I have a question related to forms in django(i'm new on it)
Look. Here i have form that looks like:

```
class ProccessAgentForm(forms.Form):
    agent_id = forms.HiddenInput()
    main_name = forms.IntegerField()
    company_name = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    company_state = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    company_city = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    company_country = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    company_post_code = forms.IntegerField()
    agent_first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    agent_last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    agent_phone = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    agent_fax = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    agent_email = forms.EmailField()
    agent_city = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    agent_post_code = forms.IntegerField()
    agent_state = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    agent_country = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    signer_first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    signer_last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    signer_title = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
```

And i parsed it like(i know it's not the best choice):

```
form = ProccessAgentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ....
    designated_company = DesignatedCompany()
    designated_company.pdf_link = copyright_agent.pdf_link
    designated_company.name = request.POST['company_name']
    designated_company.address = company_address
    designated_company.city = request.POST['company_city']
    designated_company.post_code = request.POST['company_post_code']
    designated_company.state = request.POST['company_state']
    designated_company.country = request.POST['company_country']
    designated_company.save()

    agent = DesignatedAgent()
    agent.company = designated_company
    agent.first_name = request.POST['agent_first_name']
    agent.last_name = request.POST['agent_last_name']
    agent.email = request.POST['agent_email']
    agent.address = agent_address
    agent.city = request.POST['agent_city']
    agent.country = request.POST['agent_country']
    agent.post_code = request.POST['agent_post_code']
    agent.state = request.POST['agent_state']
    agent.fax = request.POST['agent_fax']
    agent.phone = request.POST['agent_phone']
    agent.save()
```

and so on... How can i make it more readable? Should i split logic to forms ? I know about model Forms, but here i have foreign keys as you saw. I'd appreciate for more detailed response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i make it more readable?

First you can make it safer by using your form's `cleaned_data` instead of `request.POST` - it will contain cleaned up, sanitized, and eventually correctly typed values instead of the raw strings from the request's body.

*A bit unrelated but while we're at it: a postal code (zip code) is NOT an integer, it's a string (eventually containing only numeric characters depending on the country).*

Then you could use `objects.create()` and pass your data directly instead of creating a blank model instance, assigning all attributes manually and then saving it:

```
data = form.cleaned_data
designated_company = DesignatedCompany.objects.create(
    pdf_link=copyright_agent.pdf_link,
    name=data['company_name'],
    address=company_address,
    city=data['company_city'],
    # etc
    )
```

And finally : just use a pair of `ModelForms` instead.

> Should i split logic to forms ?

The answer is in the question.

> I know about model Forms, but here i have foreign keys as you saw.

And ? How is it a problem ? Exclude fields you don't want / can't use now from the ModelForm and use the `commit=False` flag when saving the second form so you can add the missing parts yourself.

You can even facade both forms and all this inner working in a "form-like" class of your own (a class that doesn't inherhit from `Form` but has the same API - at least the parts your interested in - and delegates to your CompanyForm and AgentForm) so the view's code don't have to bother...

Comment: Should i split logic to forms ? The answer is in the question. Sorry my english is bad, is that a yes to split the logic?

Comment: @Manza it is, indeed. As a general guideline, try to keep your views as dumb as possible, and move as much as possible of the business logic to seperate entities (models, forms, plain old python classes etc). Code that depends on the `request` object is a pain to unittest, and cannot be reused outside the request / response cycle, so the less request-dependent code the better. There's a reason why django forms take a `dict`-like object as `data`, not the full request, and there's a reason why `ModelForm`s encapsulate the whole logic of creating / updating a model instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) to automatically generate forms that create model instances on save, like this:

```
class DesignatedCompanyForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = DesignatedCompany
         fields = ['name', 'city', 'post_code', 'state', 'country']
```

There is also [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) that doesn't require separate form:

```
class DesignatedCompanyCreate(CreateView):
    model = DesignatedCompany
    fields = ['name', 'city', 'post_code', 'state', 'country']
```

(snippets aren't tested, some fixes could be needed)